# If condition with startswith and endswith error

Tags: python, startswith, ends-with

I have the split the data that starts from ( and ends )
x contains data likes (33)Knoxville, TN,,,(1)Basking Ridge, NJ
location = "".join(x.split("()"))[4:] in this split logic what condition should I gve [3:] ??

```
           if name:

        if x.startswith('(') and x.endswith(')'):

            location = "".join(x.split("()"))[3:]

            print(location)
        else:
            location = x
```

Comment: you have `endswith()` two times but you don't use `startswith()`

Comment: Please consider formatting the code correctly in your question, and don'f forget to post also the error traceback, as @furas said.

Comment: `split("()")` doesn't split on `"("` and `")"` but only on `"()"`

Comment: `re.split(r'[()]', strin)` will do split on `(` or `)`

Comment: if you don't know what to use then use both with `print()` to see what you get in both situations.

Comment: put code in question, not in comment. In question it will be readable and everyone will read it. Not everyone reads comments.

Comment: edit your data to make them more readable and show expected result.

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have after `x.split("()")` and after you use `join()`

Comment: if you want to remove `(33)` and `(1)` then get `split(")")[1]` - it doesn't need `join()`. And use `print( split(")") )` to see what you get - to learn something.

Comment: Please add an clear desired output. But also present you the example and input in amore concise way. You indent also don't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are trying to split by `(chars)` or `,`,

```
>>> s = '(1)Basking Ridge, NJ (33)Knoxville, TN'
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'\s*\([^()]*\)\s*|\s*,\s*', s)
['', 'Basking Ridge', 'NJ', 'Knoxville', 'TN']
>>> t = re.split(r'\s*\([^()]*\)\s*|\s*,\s*', s)
>>> ','.join([i for i in t if i])
'Basking Ridge,NJ,Knoxville,TN'
>>>
```

Comment: Just do a join at the last like I did.